# Gatling Load Test script

Tags: load-testing, gatling

Say I need to write a gatling Load test script that needs to call two APIs A1 and A2. It first needs to call A1 which will return a JSON payload, it needs to extract a field in the JSON payload and use that field value in calling the second API. Can anyone let me know how can I do that? This script is for Load Testing our servers restful APIs that are over HTTP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that using jsonpath checks and by saving the result to the session.

It is documented here in the [http check](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.7/http/http_check.html#http-check-jsonpath) and [session](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.7/session/index.html) pages.

This will look like this:

```scala
exec(
  http("api 1")
  .get("api1url")
  .check(jsonPath("/my/json/field").saveAs("myValue"))
)
.exec(
  http("api 2")
    .get("api2url/${myValue}")
)
```